# Invalid dropzone element

Tags: javascript, dropzone

This application is build in Laravel 7, I have the javascript pulled in with webpack. When I try to create a new Dropzone element it gives me this error:
`Uncaught Error: Invalid dropzone element.`
. This is my JavaScript code:

```
window.Dropzone = require('dropzone/dist/dropzone.js');
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$(function () {
  if (document.getElementById('pdfDropzone')) {
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#pdfDropzone", { url: "/success" });
    Dropzone.options.pdfDropzone = {
      paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
      maxFilesize: 2, // MB
      acceptedFiles: ".pdf", //
      accept: function (file, done) {
        done();
      }
    };
    $("#pdfButton").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      myDropzone.processQueue();
    });
  }
});
```

This is the HTML:

```
            <form action="/success" id="pdfDropzone" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone pdf-drop row align-content-center">
                @csrf
                <button class="dz-button col-2" id="pdfButton">
                    <i class="far fa-file-alt"></i><br>
                    PDF
                </button>
                <div class="dz-message col-8 align-self-center">Drag PDF file here or click to browse </div>
                <div class="fallback">
                    <input name="file" type="file" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

How can I remove this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by creating 2 new forms like so:

```
<div>
<form action="/pdf_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="pdfDropzone" class="uploadzone pdf-drop row align-content-center">
@csrf
<!-- Dropzone pdf-->
<button class="dz-button col-2">
<i class="far fa-file-alt"></i><br>
PDF
</button>
<div class="dz-message col-8 align-self-center">Drag PDF file here or click to browse </div>
<div class="fallback">
<input name="pdf_file" type="file" />
</div>
</form>
<!-- End Dropzone -->
<!-- Dropzone tumbnail-->
<form action="/image_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="imgDropzone" class="uploadzone img-drop col justify-content-center">
@csrf
<button class="dz-button">
<i class="far fa-file-alt"></i><br>
jpg, png, jpeg
</button>
<div class="dz-message align-self-center">Drag image file here or<br>click to browse</div>
<div class="fallback">
<input name="image_file" type="file" />
</div>
</form>
<!-- End Dropzone -->
</div>
```

Then in app.js I added this:

```
require('dropzone');

$(function () {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var dropzoneOptionsPdf = {
        paramName: "file",
        maxFilesize: 20, // MB
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        acceptedFiles: "application/pdf",
        init: function () {
            this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (file) {
                this.removeFile(file);
            });
        }
    };
    var dropzoneOptionsImage = {
        paramName: "file",
        maxFilesize: 20, // MB
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        acceptedFiles: "image/*",
        init: function () {
            this.on("success", function (file) {
                console.log("success > " + file.name);
            });
        }
    };
    var pdfDropzone = new Dropzone("#pdfDropzone", dropzoneOptionsPdf);
    var imgDropzone = new Dropzone("#imgDropzone", dropzoneOptionsImage);
});
```

I hope this helps someone with the same problem!